# How to delete large numbers of records in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I need to purge old records from Firestore, so i will need to build a batch job that querys old records and deletes them all.

My experience with SQL told me that i should do it in bulks to avoid large transaction logs but Firebase doesn't try to keep consistence do way SQL databases do.

I am using Firestore BatchWrite to delete the records so my question is: is there a limit, event that only an advisable limit, for how many records should i put in a batch? Or as long i don't get an timeout frequently i am ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Cloud Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

> A batched write can contain up to 500 operations and batching operations together reduces connection overhead resulting in faster data migration.

So it looks like the fastest way to purge old records is in batches of 500 documents.